# how do I return a javascript statement to the ajax responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax

For example:

**In the HTML page**

```
xmlHttpObj.open("GET", "url.php", true);
xmlHttpObj.onreadystatechange = function(){
   ..
   document.getElementById('divInThisPage').innerHTML = xmlHttpObj.responseText;
   ..
}
..
..

function foo(arg){
   alert(arg);
}
```

**In the url.php**

```
echo "<input type='button' value='ok' onclick=\"foo('ok')\" />";
```

The question is, why the alert won't work?

**edit:**
even if in the url.php I put a inline javascript code the button still doesn't work

```
echo "<input type='button' value='ok' onclick=\"alert('ok')\" />";
```

Comment: where is the alert? where is the ajax code? put more code please

Comment: Have you got a live example of the page?

Comment: Does your `input` element get put into the document? If so, does your browser display a JS error when you click on it?

Comment: no, I mean why the alert won't work when I click the button with the "ok" value?

Comment: @Bagong21: Do you see any JavaScript errors?  Check your browser's console.

Comment: @Jeremy, yes the input get into the document, and no error, but the button doesn't work

Comment: @Bagong: Try putting the alert directly in the `onclick` like: `onclick=\"alert('hi')\"`. If that doesn't work, or at least give an error, I'm not sure what else we can do with out more information. (What browser are you using?)

Comment: @Jeremy : I tried the inline style, but it still doesn't work, the browsers: FF 4.0 + firebug1.7, IE 8, Chrome 10, opera 10

Comment: @Jotapdiez: do you need a microscope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is why, when you click the button that has been created by your ajax request, the alert is not alerting. This is probably because the onclick event handler `foo()` has not been registered. This I *think* is browser dependent - try in a different browser and it may work.

Anyway it's not working because when you dynamically add HTML to a page like this the onclick is not being registered in your browser. You can add event listeners to an element like this:

```
function doAddEventListener(elem, eventName, fn) {
  if(elem.addEventListener ) {
       elem.addEventListener(eventName, fn, false);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
         elem.attachEvent('on'+eventName, fn);
    } 
}
```

where `fn` is the function you want to add, i.e `foo`, and `eventName` in this case would be "click", and `elem` is the element you want to add the listener to.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the same code on FF3 and it seems to work just fine. Are you sure there is no typo somewhere? Try using firebug for clues.